# The multi-part identifier > "a.surveyid" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the error :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "a.surveyid" could not be bound.

Below is the query ,what could be the issue?

```
 SELECT a.surveyid,* 
    FROM [360HRSurvey] where sempid IN ( 
     SELECT  a.EmpCode  
     FROM surveyusers a  
     where a.surveyid = 80 and a.EmpCode NOT IN (
      SELECT p.EmpID    
      FROM empsurveyselection p 
      WHERE p.surveyid =80)
    and empid =   ( 
      SELECT empid 
      from [360HRSurveyEmployee] 
      where surveyid = 80)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.surveyid,* FROM [360HRSurvey] 
inner join ( SELECT a.EmpCode,a.surveyid FROM surveyusers a where a.surveyid =     
80 and a.EmpCode NOT IN (SELECT p.EmpID FROM empsurveyselection p WHERE 
p.surveyid =80)) a 
on a.EmpCode=sempid 
where  empid = ( SELECT empid from [360HRSurveyEmployee] where surveyid = 80)
```

Comment: some syntax errors Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: @smartestvega check now

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `surveyid` not `a.surveyid`. Because `surveyusers as a` declare in `sub-query` so you can not access `a.surveyid` in main query.

Comment: there is no surveyid column in 360HRSurvey hence this will give error

Comment: @SmartestVEGA what do you want this column to return? The number 80?

Comment: yes, i will remove that where clause of survey id in future , so i need to return all survey id appended to the main function

Comment: for that you need to use join.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error was explained in [Jaimin Soni's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103012/the-multi-part-identifier-a-surveyid-could-not-be-bound/103013#103013).

Since you want to include `surveyid` in the result and this is not an attribute of the `[360HRSurvey]` table, you could just use `SELECT 80 AS surveyid, * ...` for this particular query. If the `surveyid` is not fixed though - in a more complex query - you can join to the table that has this attribute. Assuming that this table is `surveyusers` and that there is a `FOREIGN KEY` from `[360HRSurvey] (sempid)` that `REFERENCES surveyusers(EmpCode)`, the query can be rewritten:

```
SELECT a.surveyid, hrs.* 
FROM [360HRSurvey] AS hrs
   JOIN surveyusers AS a 
      ON a.EmpCode = hrs.sempid 
WHERE a.surveyid = 80           -- this condition can be altered or removed
  AND a.EmpCode NOT IN (
          SELECT p.EmpID    
          FROM empsurveyselection p 
          WHERE p.surveyid = a.surveyid )
  AND a.empid = (               -- unclear if it's a.empid or hrs.empid
         SELECT hrsemp.empid 
         FROM [360HRSurveyEmployee] AS hrsemp
         WHERE hrsemp.surveyid = a.surveyid ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT su.surveyid,b.* FROM surveyusers SU 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM [360HRSurvey] where sempid  NOT IN (
SELECT a.EmpCode FROM surveyusers a 
where a.EmpCode IN (SELECT p.EmpID 
  FROM empsurveyselection p where deptid = 9 )
and empid IN   
( SELECT empid from [360HRSurveyEmployee] ))) B
ON su.EmpCode = b.sempid 
Order by surveyid desc
```

Fixed it myslelf

Comment: The `where deptid = 9` was not part of the original query.

Comment: yes i intetionaly added for a business logic change thanks